# Distance of a vector from a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to find the distance between the vector $(1,0,0,1)$ to a subspace $L=(Sp\{(1,0,2,1),(3,1,4,4),(1,1,0,2)\})^{\perp }$ .

Now, the thing I did first to solve it was this $L = (Sp\{(1,0,2,1),(1,1,0,2)\})^{\perp }$
because $(3,1,4,4)=2(1,0,2,1)+(1,1,0,2)$ but I'm not sure it's 100% right.

Now, $L^{\perp } =  Sp\{(1,0,2,1),(1,1,0,2)\}$ so  I took a vector from $L$, $(a,b,c,d)$,
and did this:

$$((a,b,c,d).(1,0,2,1))=a+2c+d=0\,\,⇒\,\,(*)\,\,d=-a-2c$$

$$((a,b,c,d).(1,1,0,2))=a+b+2d=0\,\,⇒\,\,((*)) \,\,b=4c+a$$

But now I'm stuck, and I don't know how to proceed. I don't know if I made a mistake but I don't know how to get the basis for $L$ now.

Can someone please help me?

(Sorry for my english. :( )

Comment: This looks right. You do not in fact need to find a basis for the orthogonal complement. Project onto the $2$-dimensional plane you have (using various techniques) and then what is left over?

Comment: What definition of "distance" from  subspace to  vector are you using?  Do you want the shortest distance from the point (1, 0, 0, 1) to the hyper-plane spanned by those vectors?

Comment: @TedShifrin I wanted to find a basis so I could use the Gram–Schmidt process to make it an Orthonormal basis. But the problem is that I don't know how do I find the basis for L, I mean how do I get the vectors from this                                                        
((a,b,c,d).(1,0,2,1))=a+2c+d=0⇒(∗)d=−a−2c

((a,b,c,d).(1,1,0,2))=a+b+2d=0⇒((∗))b=4c+a

Comment: I'm telling you to forget about $L^\perp$ and project just on $L$. The projection on $L^\perp$ is what you get when you subtract the projection on $L$ from the original vector. Why?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a general approach using least squares techniques.
Let $b$ be the vector to be projected on
$L= S^\perp$ where $S = \text{span}\{s_1,s_2,...s_n\}$.

Define the matrix $A = [s_1\ s_2\ \cdots s_n]$ so that the column space of $A$ is $S$.

If the solution to $A^\top A x = A^\top b$ is $x_0$,
then $Ax_0=b_0$ is the projection of $b$ onto $S$.

Hence, the projection of $b$ onto $L$ is $b-b_0$.